# Is it possible to connect physical nodes to a docker selenium hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

When I spin up an AWS instance with a docker selenium image, would I be able to connect nodes that are not running the docker image as a node?

For example, use an AWS instance with the docker-selenium image and then attempt to connect a MacBook to a node (with safari) assuming the networking has been set up correctly, would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this would not work, as all interaction between nodes and hub is done through http as far as I remember.

Have you tried it?

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/254 

I've tried it, I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong